# Javascript: I am trying to write a calculate function that will "add" two numbers and print the result out as a string, but my syntax isn't working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a calculate function that will "add" two numbers and print the result out as a string, but my syntax isn't working. Can you please look at my code and tell me how I can fix it? Later I would like to add more mathematical functions like divide and multiple that can be plugged in. Thanks.

```
var add = function(x,y){
  return x+y;
 };

var calculate = function(string,x,y){

  if(string === "add"){
    var result = console.log(x + "+ " y + "= " + add(x,y));
    return result;
  }
 };

calculate("add",5,6);
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` between the string literal and the variable `y`.

Comment: @Bergi Big thanks!

Comment: `console.log` returns `undefined` which is then assigned to `result`!

Answer (score 2):

You have missed a `+` sign before `y`.
This:

```
var result = console.log(x + "+ " y + "= " + add(x,y));
```

must be

```
var result = console.log(x + "+ " + y + "= " + add(x,y));
```

Anyway, your function does not look correct. `console.log` returns nothing, and your `result` variable will always be evaluated to `undefined`, and function will always return `undefined` as well.
Also, your **`calculate`** function does actually **calculate and output result** which can be not that transparent for someone who calls this method and breaks [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Probably, it is a better idea to separate calculation and presentation:

```js
function add(x,y){
  return x+y;
}

function calculate(action,x,y){
  if(action === "add") {
    return x + "+ " + y + "= " + add(x,y);
  }
}

var result = calculate("add",5,6);
console.log(result);
```

You may also want to replace `if (action === "add")` with `switch` statement in the future when you will have more than two actions :)